# Bootstrap Tooltip Content Dismisses before iOS VoiceOver can read it

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, voiceover

I am using bootstrap tooltips on my website and I am experiencing an issue in reading the tooltips via iOS VoiceOver utility. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and the Boostrap Accessibility Plugin. I've made a example [here](http://stout.hampshire.edu/~jci12/stack)

The html on that page is as follows:

```
<a href="#!" tabindex="0" class="tooltip-a" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover focus" title="Tooltips are cool">This is a tooltip. <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">tooltip available</span></a>
```

From iOS VoiceOver, you can focus on the a to open the tooltip, but if you try to swipe to move the VO cursor to the next item, the tooltip dismisses and you would never know there was content there at all. If you attempt to touch the tooltip to read it, VO starts to read but soon stops because the tooltip goes away. I'm guessing this is because the a has lost focus. I can't figure out how to make it so the a does not lose focus when the VO cursor moves to the tooltip content.

I haven't modified the bootstrap or bootstrap-accessibility .js files. I can try if that's where the error is, though I feel like if it was I'd have found anyone else talking about this.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. I'm quite desperate to fix this.

Comment: It occurred to me that I'm using bootstrap 3.3.2 so if this has been fixed in more recent updates let me know. I'm afraid right now to update in case it breaks any other kluges on the site, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my version of Bootstrap from 3.3.2 to 3.3.6 fixed the issue. :)